# How to handle multi page tours with Bootstrap-Tour and dynamic paths?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tour

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Bootstrap Tour to work across multiple dynamic url pages.  My tour starts on the users page `/<user>` and I'm having them click a photo gallery and want tour to continue from that gallery page `/<user>/<gallery>`.

I'm using reflex because I want the user to select a gallery they have and the tour to continue on from the new page.  I've tried like every possible combination of using/not using `reflex`, `onNext`, `path`, and `redirect` I can think of and what you'd think would work logically doesn't work at all so I don't even know...   I thought `path` is used to tell the step what page to step should fire on but instead no matter what I try the script keeps trying to redirect to the `path` I specify and when my path contains a regex and its like trying to redirect to the regex which obviously doesn't work so its all a mess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so after hours of messing and trying various combinations of things I finally figured it out, the docs on the site need to be updated for sure.  The example it gives for using regex with path is `path: Regexp("/\/url\/[^/]+/i")` which I knew was wrong from the beginning but still went with for a while trying to figure things out, and then of course when I did correct it how it should be I must not of been using the right combo of other properties.

When all is said and done, you can use path to tell the script this rule applies to this page BUT to do so you must also pass `false` to `redirect`.

So to accomplish what I was wanting, the first step actually doesn't need any `onNext`, `path`, or `redirect` property set, you can simply set `reflex: true` so it auto goes to the next step when your element is clicked, then the key is on your following step set `path` to what your page should be at and `redirect: false` set so it doesn't try to automatically redirect to your `path` which is a regex and not a valid url path.

Comment: What format do you use for the path for it to work? I'm using `path: new RegExp(/regexp/)` but it's not doing what I expect it to do.